# Mongodb connection disconnected after 2-3 hrs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lambda, aws-api-gateway

Mongodb connection diconnected after 2-3 hrs.

Network access - 0.0.0.0/0

My backend application is running on AWS Lamba on the top of API gateway. Its a monoletic application which has 20+ endpoints.

I am trying to connect mongo from there - First 2-3 hrs it is working fine. Then I am getting this below error. -

```
ab64f03c-c8f9-43fb-8cb0-20197289717f    INFO    MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:791:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:766:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /var/task/db.js:12:7 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-4ugleph-shard-00-00.btwmhhb.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-4ugleph-shard-00-01.btwmhhb.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-4ugleph-shard-00-02.btwmhhb.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-xsqkyc-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

When I ran the same code from Ec2, it is working fine.

How I am connecting mongo -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const chalk = require('chalk');

// Mongodb ServerUrl


const connectUrl = mongodb+srv://abbakid:<password>@abbakid-dev.erpttih.mongodb.net/Abbakid?retryWrites=true&w=majority



(async () => {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(connectUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      });
      console.log(chalk.yellow('MongoDB connected...', connectUrl));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(chalk.red('Error in DB connection: ' + err));
    }
})();

module.exports = mongoose;
```